# Detect command running in background

Tags: exec, php

I am using php and its command line interface to execute a script. During script execution I call some commands in the background (some of which are quite time consuming), using the following code from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

The main script might get called a couple of times before all commands have completely executed.

Is there a way to check before I execute the command if it is already running in the background from a previous execution of the script?

Comment: log to db or file and check that

Comment: @Dagon: That was my first instinct, but I wasn't sure how to implement it. The main script exits before the commands in the background complete, and the commands in the background don't do any logging themselves (I can't change them either,) leaving me with no reliable way to know when to log that a command has finished executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could keep track of the background commands is to store the information in a file somewhere. The name of the command might not be unique across the system, so you can't check for that. You could store the process ID in a config file, and check the command by string:

```
function execInBackground($cmd)
{
    $running = false;

    // get the state of our commands
    $state = json_decode(file_get_contents("state.json"));

    // check if the command we want to run is already running and remove commands that have ended
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($state->processes); $i++)
    {
        // check if the process is running by the PID
        if (!file_exists("/proc/" . $state->processes[$i]->pid))
        {
            // this command is running already, so remove it from the list
            unset($state->processes[$i]);
        }

        else if ($cmd === $state->processes[$i]->command)
        {
            $running = true;
        }
    }

    // reorder our array since it's probably out of order
    $state->processes = array_values($state->processes);

    // run the command silently if not already running
    if (!$running)
    {
        $process = proc_open($cmd . " > /dev/null &", array(), $pipes);
        $procStatus = proc_get_status($process);

        $state->processes[] = array("command" => $cmd, "pid" => $procStatus["pid"]);
    }

    // save the new state of our commands
    file_put_contents("state.json", json_encode($state));
}
```

The config file would look something like this:

```
{
    "processes": [
        {
            "command": "missilecomm launch -v",
            "pid": 42792
        }
    ]
}
```

(I am of the JSON "persuasion", but you can use any format you want ;) )

This wouldn't work if you *sometimes* wanted to run the same command string more than once.

Because of how `execInBackground()` clears the finished commands, it would only work on Linux. You would have to find another way to check if a process ID exists on Windows. This code isn't tested, and I'm not sure if my `proc_*` calls are correct, either.